# execution of module bootstrap

Tags: zend-framework

Is there a way to have base bootstrap and module bootstrap?

this is my app structure

```
- application
  - modules
    - admin
      - controllers
      - Bootstrap.php
    - public
      - controllers
      - Bootstrap.php
  - Bootstrap.php
- libraries
```

When I test my app only the base bootstrap is executed.
I forced the execution of the modules bootstrap with this (in the base bootstrap):

```
$modules = array('admin', 'public');
foreach ($modules as $module) {
    $path = APP_PATH . '/modules/' . $module . '/Bootstrap.php';
    $class = ucfirst($module) . '_Bootstrap.php';
    include_once $path;
    $bootstrap = new $class($this);
    $bootstrap->bootstrap();
}
```

Only with this I can execute bootstrap of modules.
Is there another way?

Comment: maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9853170/default-bootstrap-overrides-admin-bootstrap

Answer (score 1):

The module resource runs the module bootstraps. This is triggered by the presence of:

```
resources.modules[] = ""
```

in your `application.ini`, or you can manually bootstrap the modules in your main bootstrap class as you have.